# Insert data from one database table to other database table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Two Database with same table structure.

One is in local SQL on my computer and other is on Live SQL Database.

Now i want to insert Live Database Table data to local database table.

Any Idea?

Comment: Linked servers? OpenRowset? these are the first 2 options that pops to my mind

Comment: You can use the data import/export tool or setup a link server and use an insert statement. Or even OpenRowset

Comment: i dont have VPS. i used my godaddy server.

Comment: If they're on the same physical SQL Server, just copy from one database to another.  If they are on a separate instance of SQL Server, just link the servers, and then copy from one server.database to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use the DATA IMPORT functionality.  However, there is another fairly easy way to do it, **provided you're not talking millions of rows.**

Basically you run a SELECT query on the table you want to pull from that creates an INSERT statement for each row:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO MyTable 
    (col1, col2, col3) 
    VALUES (
        ''' + CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(25)) + ''',
        ''' + CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(25)) + ''',
        ''' + CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(25)) + '''' 
    + ')'   
FROM MyTable
```

The result set will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)  VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)  VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)  VALUES ('val1','val2','val3')
```

You can add IDENTITY INSERT as well, of course.

So, just copy the result set into a QUERY window for the test server and execute it.  I've done this many times myself when I'm copying from multiple tables.

I will add that sometimes this is easier (for smaller datasets) than trying to figure out how to link the servers.